# Using bootstrap how can I build this layout with the cards arranged one way on widescreens and another way on mobile?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Im using bootstrap 5.x and I can't quite get this layout. Can someone suggest a way to achieve this so the cards are like the left image on desktop/ wide screens and like the right image on smaller width mobile screens? I can get the mobile view to show A-B-C-D-E... But what I want is A-B-C-E-D.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For different pixel layout, you can have some help from bootstrap.
You need to define a parent  and take child  how much you need,
then set parent 's class name is 'row'. For child div,for large device=> class name will be col-lg-6. For small device set classname => col-lg-12. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/698f7.png)

Comment: You're missing the point. If I do that the mobile view will have the cards A-B-C-D-E but I want the mobile view to be A-B-C-E-D. Note the last two.